# How to sort an array with an year and custom string?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this

```
Q1 2017
Q3 2017
Q3 2012
Q4 2015
Q4 2017
Q2 2017
```

Q = Quarter of the year

I want to sort this array like the following

```
Q2 2012
Q4 2015
Q1 2017
Q2 2017
Q3 2017
Q4 2017
```

The sorting is on year but in each year it is on quarter. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: I don't think it is possible with those php sort functions.

Comment: Q1, Q2 these are keys of your array?

Comment: `Q2 2012` this complete is the array key.

Comment: @Bhaskar Is it possible if only Q1 and Q2 are the keys. not the year?

Comment: @Ahmad, check my answer. Array has always unique keys, In your case, if Q1, Q2 are keys they will conflict e.g. Q1(key) - 2015 and Q1 - 2017 - these are two things, in this case, keys are same with different values, can't be poosible

Answer (score 0):

I tried as I understand your question. Hope this help.

```
$arr = array (
   array ('Q1',2017),
   array ('Q3',2017),
   array ('Q3',2012),
   array ('Q4',2015),
   array ('Q4',2017),
   array ('Q2',2017),

 );
$new = array();
foreach($arr as $subarr){
   $new[$subarr[1]][] = $subarr[0];
   sort($new[$subarr[1]]);
}
ksort($new);
$finalarr = array();
foreach($new as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
        $finalarr[] = array($v, $key);
    }
}

 echo "<pre>"; print_r($finalarr);
```

[PHP Code Demo](https://3v4l.org/lgPgO)

**Update:** As per your comment, Here is updated code:

```
$arr = 
   array ('Q1 2017'=>'some value', 'Q3 2017'=>'some value', 'Q3 2012'=>'some value', 'Q4 2015'=>'some value', 'Q4 2017'=>'some value', 'Q2 2017'=>'some value');

$new = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$subarr){
   $tempArr =  explode(' ', $key);   
   $new[$tempArr[1]][$tempArr[0]] = $subarr;
   asort($new[$tempArr[1]]);
}

ksort($new);
$secondarr = array();
foreach($new as $k=>$v){
    ksort($v);
    $secondarr[$k] = $v;
}

foreach($secondarr as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
        $newkey = $k.' '.$key;
        $finalarr[$newkey] = $v;
    }
}

 echo "<pre>"; print_r($finalarr);
```

[Php Demo Code](https://3v4l.org/ajAa0)

Comment: *`Q2 2012` complete is the array key*

Comment: then what is the value of key?

Comment: i-e `array('Q2 2017' => array(), 'Q1 2017' => array())`

Comment: @Ahmad, Please check updated answer, hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmad try usort() like below:

```
<?php
$arr = array (
   array ('Q1',2017),
   array ('Q3',2017),
   array ('Q3',2012),
   array ('Q4',2015),
   array ('Q4',2017),
   array ('Q2',2017),

 );

function sortArr($a, $b){
    if($a[1] < $b[1]){
        return -1;
    }
    else if($a[1] == $b[1]){
        return ($a[0] < $b[0] ? -1 : 1);
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

usort($arr, "sortArr");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```