# How can I sort mySQL results in an individual order?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM animals WHERE id = ?');
$pdo->execute(array($id));
$animals = $pdo->fetchAll();

foreach ($animals as $row) { 
  echo "<li>".$row["category"]."/".$row["name"]."</li>";
}
```

My result is:

three / fox

four / mouse

one / cat

three / hedgehog

two / bird

one / elefant

one / fish

four / zebra

three / monkey

two / dog

I want to sort now the results by category. Not by first letter, but by logical order. So in the end my result should be:

one / cat

one / elefant

one / fish

two / bird

two / dog

three / fox

three / hedgehog

three / monkey

four / mouse

four / zebra

Of course this does not work with ORDER BY ASC. But is there a way to define those categories "one" "two" "three" "four" and say: Print all "one" first, then "two"... and inside this categories order by name?

Comment: If you had an extra column CategoryNumber, which was an int representing the category, then `ORDER BY CategoryNumber, Name` would work. Your problem is trying to sort a string as if it was a number.

Comment: Think you should do it in your php code. convert "string numbers" to number and sort it

Comment: Add a column in your DB named "order", for all "one" insert "1", for "two" insert "2" - then you can use the ORDER BY function of SQL :)

Comment: check this, that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320777/how-to-sort-an-array-with-an-year-and-custom-string/43321318#43321318

Comment: @Twinfriends Yes, thought about that. But I was wondering if it would not be a better solution with php

Comment: Does `category` have a finite set of possible values, or is it unlimited?

Comment: @JakubMatczak It is finite. I have only "one" "two" "three" and "four"

Comment: PHP asort could be something for you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: It is also known as "bad database design"... But yes, you could create a comparable array in PHP (one => 1, two => 2...) and so on, and use that.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I look actually for a solution with good database design :)

Comment: Is there anything in that db that you can map or join to a number column?The real answer here is to map the words to number and update your database column to int

Comment: @Jarla If you're looking for a solution with good DB design, then change it. If you're just looking for a working solution, PHP asort function could do the job for you.

Comment: @Mihai at this moment no

Comment: @Jarla then redesign the database-values. For instance, change the `one` to `1`, `two` to `2` and so on. If you need them to be written, you can change that on the PHP-side instead.

Comment: @Twinfriends Change it means. For "one" make another column "1". For "two" "2" and so on? (By the way the words ONE TWO THREE are just placeholder. In my code that are different words)

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I took only ONE TWO THREE to demonstrate the sorting here in the question. In my code it is something like BANANAS APPLES STRAWBERRYS

Comment: Oh, if they're just placeholder then simply change their value to 1, 2, 3 and 4. If there's really no need that there's te word "one" "two" and so... then you haven't to add a new column. And you can update all these values with 4 simple `UPDATE` statements. Otherwise as I said, add a column and place the numeric values inside, so that you can use ORDER BY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql custom order by and alphabetical order by:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024854/mysql-custom-order-by-and-alphabetical-order-by)

Comment: @Twinfriends No no no, there just a placeholder here in the question. In my real code, they have to be BANANAS and APPLES

Comment: Oh okay. So as I said... Another column, or you do it with PHP by using asort ... or you use the provided answer from Jakub below, should work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said in your coment that "one" "two" "three" and "four" are the only possible values.

Therefore you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to achieve that.

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM animals 
WHERE id = ? 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(category,'one,two,three,four') ASC, name ASC
```

`FIND_IN_SET(category, 'one,two,three,four')` returns index (from 1 to n) of position of given `category` value in set of comma separated values `'one,two,three,four'`.

So for example if `category = 'three'`, then `FIND_IN_SET(category,'one,two,three,four') = 3`

Comment: That looks nice! I will test it

Comment: Working very well! Actually exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use FIELD to order on customize. 
 `SELECT * FROM animals WHERE id = ? ORDER BY FIELD(category, 'one','two','three')`